# C - how to initialize a 2d array of unknown size

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

It is required that I have a 2d array of ints with 3 columns and an undetermined number of rows. How can I create an array such that I can add new rows as needed?

Comment: What do you know about pointers and dynamic memory allocation? I suggest you read about that in your books.

Comment: I have googled for some time trying to find the answer.

Comment: Learn how to use malloc, realloc, and free.  They are part of the C dynamic memory allocation library.

Comment: Please buy a couple of books instead of random searching. You wouldn't do something like simple searching for learning a spoken or written language, would you?

Comment: I am aware of the existence of these methods, I am attempting to learn how to use them for a basic question.

Comment: How about starting by posting the code where you declare your array?

Comment: Declare a pointer as `int (*p)[3];` and initialize it as `p = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*p));`  If you need to grow it, it's `p = realloc(p, new_nrows * sizeof(*p));`  When done, free it with `free(p);`  That's your specific use case.

Comment: I have never seen syntax like `int (*p)[3]` anywhere before. Yikes!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a basic understanding of dynamic allocation for an array (like an array of integers), then a 2-d array is just an array of rows.

To deal with an array of integers of dynamically determined length, you use a pointer to `int`:

```
int *array1;
```

So, for your 2-dimensional array, use a pointer to a row:

```
row_type *array2;
```

Each row is three integers.

```
typedef int row_type[3];
```

But, you can write it without the type alias as:

```
int (*array2)[3];
```

which is read as "array2 is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`".

Then you can allocate memory for it in the idiomatic way:

```
array2 = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array2));
```

Comment: `... = malloc( sizeof(int[cols][rows]) );` is probably more readable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use a normal array with triple size of the original. For example:

```
int * create_array(int n)
{
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3 * n)
    return array;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
// simulate array[y][x]
int value = array[x + y * 3];
```

Comment: Nah, the columns are fixed, so use a genuine array pointer and let the compiler generate the 2D indices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either a list of 3-element arrays (treating that as columns) - that could be even simple single-linked list, defined similar to this:

```
typedef struct _list_t
{
    int m_rows[3];
    struct _list_t * m_next;
} list_t;
```

or an array of 3-element arrays, that will grow using `realloc()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use struct and pointer to make a linked list.

```
typedef struct int_list {
    int i[3];
    struct int_list *next;
} List;
```

So, when you need new row, just use malloc() to add new node. And use free() when you want to remove the node from the linked list.